# How do I open an image in prolog and display it in terminal?

Tags: image, terminal, prolog, jpeg, display

I'm working on a minesweeper program and would like to know if there is a way to open an image file from my desktop and display it when running during my application which runs on the terminal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show some effort made.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `open image.jpeg` and it will open the image whenever you call it in your bash code. If you want to open it with a specific program, do `open -a Program image.jpeg`